# JQuery Validation Runs but quickly refresh the page which cause for failure of function on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//$('.this_btn').click(function(){

    //$('#myModal').modal('show');

    //setTimeout(function() {enter code here
        //$('#myModal').modal('hide')   
    //}, 5000);
//})


/*Validation*/


var forum = $('#popup_form');



forum.validate({
    keyup:false,
    debug: false,
    rules:{
        title:{
            required:true
            },

        f_name:{
            required:true,
            minlength: 4
            },

        email:{
            email:true,
            required:true
            },

        t_phn:{
            required:true,
            digits: true
            },

        //t_phn:'validateDecimal',

        call_me:{
            required:true
            },

        d_amount:{
            required:true
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit(
                //alert('done')
            );
        },

        success: 'valid',


    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      $.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
        return $(value).popover("hide");
      });
      return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
        var _popover;
        console.log(value.message);
        _popover = $(value.element).popover({
          trigger: "manual",
          placement: "top",
          content: value.message,
          template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
        });
        _popover.data("popover").options.content = value.message;
        return $(value.element).popover("show");
      });
    }
    });

$('.this_btn').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked')

    if(forum.valid()==false){
        console.log('if condition') 
        //$('#myModal').modal('show');
        //$('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
    else{
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //alert('Thank you');
    console.log('working')  
    //$('#myModal').delay(4000)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide') 
    }, 5000);


        }


}); 



 })


</script>
```

Hello, Is there someone who would help me in this... My validation is working perfectly but when I submit the form after being valid, then I'm trying to run a function and that function is to popup a module... but now when i press submit the function gets call but the page refreshes quickly which cause the failure of my popup function...

(Sorry, My English isn't good enough.. I hope you can understand what I want to ask!! Thank you)

Comment: Here you go >> http://jsfiddle.net/WebMaster001/8e2Up/
Thank you for a quick reply.. I'm using Bootstrap btw...

Comment: @RobH Yes, .this_btn is a submit button.... I'm using http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/  validation plugin...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WebMaster001/3Gp8N/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `submitHandler` if you end it by `return false` it will not submit the form.  So all you need to do next is move your form submittal into your setTimeout script:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    console.log('working')  
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide') 
        $('#popup_form').submit();//<-- form submit is here now
    }, 5000);
    return false;//this prevents submitHandler from automatically submitting the form
},
```

You do not need to do anything at all in your `.this_btn` handler.  Just remove it.

Comment: That's what I had done before checking this... Thank you btw and that was the way to do it...

Comment: Excellent, @Muzamil, you should either accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark beside it), or make your own and accept that.